# DiscretizeRegion on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: regions, raspberry-pi

Running `DiscretizeRegion@Cuboid[]` from the documentation under [Raspbian](https://www.raspbian.org/) on the [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) 2, Mathematica version 10.0.0.0, gives the following response:

> DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region Cuboid[{0,0,0}].

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 9):

The Raspberry Pi build does not include certain components. In particular, TetGenLink and TriangleLink are not available which will affect region discretization (and PDE solving over regions etc.)

**Update**

This has been improved in the latest `wolfram-engine` release (namely `wolfram-engine_10.3.1+2016012407_armhf.deb`).

[image]

There may still be bits and pieces of the computational geometry functionality that are lagging behind in the Raspberry Pi release, for example boolean operations on meshes.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I've tried the option for `DiscretizeRegion` you suggested, unfortunately it seems to return the same error.

Comment: @image_doctor My mistake; I wasn't using the released version. Will update the answer if I find a workaround.