# DiscretizeRegion on Raspberry Pi

Tags: regions, raspberry-pi

I'm using Mathematica v13.1 on a Raspberry Pi 400. I'm trying discretize a region with a circular hole in it. But instead, the circle gets discretized:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 > 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
RegionPlot[R]
DiscretizeRegion[R]
```

[image: The actual region and its discretization]

As mentioned in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88222/discretizeregion-on-raspberry-pi-2), the RPi version has some problems with computational geometry.

Is it a bug in the RPi version? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Your code works as expected on Win10-64 in MMA 12.3.1. I don't have access to an RPI so I can't offer more insight, but I think you should report this to Wolfram Support.

Comment: I've contacted Wolfram Support. They've acknowledged the issue and reported it to the developers. Until it's fixed, one can use
`R = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 > 1 || x > 0.99, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];`
It's not perfect, but I can't think of anything better.